# Functions are not valid as a React child. Conditional Rendering through Constant and not function

Tags: reactjs

Tried to learn from all similar questions but all or most of them are about call of functions by adding () after the name inside JSX.
I am not sure why problem is coming in my scenario. I have to put a list of Alerts through conditional JSX where [Alert.js] just export an array;

```
export default [{ "alert_name": "HeavyRain", ...},{ "alert_name": "Cyclone", ...},{ "alert_name": CloudBurst", ...}]
```

Conditional JSX Display (might be causing problem):

```
class dashalert extends Component {
    render() {
        const alerts = Alert.map((alert, idx) => {
             let icon = ['r-margin', 'wi'];
             if (alert.alert_name === 'HeavyRain') icon = [...icon, 'wi-rain'];
             else if (alert.alert_name === 'Cyclone') icon = [...icon, 'wi-hurricane'];
             else if (alert.alert_name === 'CloudBurst') icon = [...icon, 'wi-thunderstorm'];
             return (
                 <Col key={idx}>
                   <Card>
                      <Card.Body>
                          <h3><i className={icon.join(' ')} /> {alert.alert_name}</h3>                       
                      </Card.Body>
                   </Card>
                 </Col>
                );
           });
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {alerts}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default dashalert;
```

Main Component Calling this display:

```
class MyDashboard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Row>
                    {dashalerts}
                </Row>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}
export default MyDashboard;
```

Not able to figure it our Why the error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in div (created by Row)
    in Row (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ForwardRef(Bootstrap(Row)) (at Dashboard/index.js:18)
    in Aux (at Dashboard/index.js:17)
    in MyDashboard (at AdminLayout/index.js:53)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dashAlerts` is a component and you should render it like one. Also note that React component names must being with Uppercase letter.

You can update your code to like below

```
import DashAlerts from '/path/to/dashalert';
class MyDashboard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Row>
                    <Dashalerts />
                </Row>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}
export default MyDashboard;
```

Comment: Your solution works, But Must begin with Uppercase is a requirement for specific browser or whole react framework.